# The LEGO Logo Font

Tags: lego-group

I am looking for a font that matches as close as can be to the LEGO logo font in the picture bellow:
[image]
It does not need to be outlined in yellow or in black, I can do that with my software. Also, it doesn't need to be italic as I can do that with the software too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would seem to me that the original design of this logo, as it was first conceived in 1949 would have been drawn by hand, without the use of modern graphics tools. So I'm not sure there is a font you could import into your Word programs and the like, but options are still available. Consider trying out this font generator that can simulate all-caps text into what they call "Legothick."

https://www.urbanfonts.com/fonts/Legothick.htm

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! After some more research on the website I found a downloadable version [here](https://www.urbanfonts.com/fonts/Legothick.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the update. It will be useful to know where to find this font in the future.

Comment: Im preety sure Lego would of already digitized this font a long time ago. Why would they not? Its preety easy too considering the .SVG format, and 99% of computer fonts are actually vectors now too. I have no idea where to find the actual font file though. Maybe lego just has been preety good at keeping it secured in their computers?

Comment: I'm sure LEGO doesn't want people copying their font to make fake copies that look just like real LEGO.

Comment: @WilliamV.: I agree TLC may see no *benefit* in *distributing* the font. However, copying the exact letters "LEGO" (rather than writing something - anything - else with the font) is about the only thing for which one would *not* need the font. Any rendition would do as a base for vectorization, including all printed logos from boxes and catalogues.